# Visual Studio Code showing" Please download and install a JDK to compile your project..." Althought I downloaded and install the newest JDK version

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jiQg.png)

Now I cannot run, debug any file. Althought I downloaded and install the newest JDK version. 1 day ago it couldn't run and debug any java file. Can you help me? I am a newbie. Thank you

Comment: I got the same warning message today. :/ I don't know what happend

Answer (score 2):

This threw me off as well.  My unfamiliarity with configuring Java through VS Code was what made it confusing to me.

As stated by @Marcus-p The warning is correct... you will want to update your settings.  Yet knowing that the "settings" are contained within the `settings.json` file is *not* clear.

Since the `settings.json` file is part of VS Code, and is global to all projects, it doesn't appear within your projects file list.  Here's how to open it for editing:

1. Open the command palette (F1 or Ctrl + Shift + P)
2. Type in the string: 'Open Settings' *(without apostrophe's)*
3. Find the option for opening the JSON file.

From there, you can add the appropriate configuration for one or more Java installations.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following the warning suggestion? Try to edit settings.json.

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [{
    "name": "JavaSE-11",
    "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.13",
    "sources": "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.13/lib/src.zip",
    "javadoc": "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api",
    "default": true
}]
```

Just adjust this to your installation directory and java version.